# Solr with MySQL returns no result

Tags: php, mysql, solr

I was trying to connect Apache Solr with MySQL. While indexing, it fetches all records, but indexed nothing. Please see the screenshots below.

This is my schema.xml change.

```xml
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> -
<field name="loc_code" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="loc_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

Here is a screenshot of the Data Import Handler after the import finished

[image]

Can someone help me to figure out where I went wrong ?

Comment: Please don't post code and error messages as screenshots.  Text is searchable, but images aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Solved now !!!. This was because of the incorrect mapping of table column name in data-config.xml

Source [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036694/dataimporthandler-is-not-indexing-mysql-table-in-solr-admin)